# populate jquery datepicker on both page load and calendar click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a jquery ui form(modal popup) where I have startDate and endDate input fields. On calendar icon click it user can select the date and it will display datetime in custom format e.g. "2017-08-03 01:00:00" but I want to populate this current datetime in startDate field and current datetime +1 hour in endDate field when the form loads up on the screen.
My custom function for startDate input field

```
   $( function() {
    $( "#startDate" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm',
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif", 
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date",

        onSelect: function(datetext){

            var d = new Date(); // for now

            var h = d.getHours();
            h = (h < 10) ? ("0" + h) : h ;

            var m = d.getMinutes();
            m = (m < 10) ? ("0" + m) : m ;

            var s = d.getSeconds();
            s = (s < 10) ? ("0" + s) : s ;

            datetext = datetext + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            strDate = datetext;

            $('#startDate').val(datetext);
        }

    });
} );
```

but when I tried on pageload function something like below using setDate

```
$("startDate").datepicker('setDate', 'strDate');
```

it shows current date only e.g. "2017-07-29" in the startDate input box instead of something like this "2017-07-29 01:00:00"

I also tried $(document).ready using same function but coudn't succeed. How can I achieve to populate date input on page load with both current date and time?

Comment: You can trigger a click event like this:
`$("#startDate").trigger("click");` under $(document).ready function.

Comment: your custom onSelect function only alters the textbox value, not the datepicker. the datepicker can't deal with time . So you need to run the same thing at page load to alter the textbox contents, as well as the datepicker setDate method.

Comment: **OPTION 1** (easiest/fastest): https://stackoverflow.com/a/18979888/3407923. -------------------------------------------------- **OPTION 2** (best/reliable): https://stackoverflow.com/a/2155546/3407923.

Answer (score 0):

use `{timepicker:false}` in the datepicker properties. like this:

```
   $( function() {
    $( "#startDate" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm',
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif", 
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date",
        timepicker:false,
        onSelect: function(datetext){

            var d = new Date(); // for now

            var h = d.getHours();
            h = (h < 10) ? ("0" + h) : h ;

            var m = d.getMinutes();
            m = (m < 10) ? ("0" + m) : m ;

            var s = d.getSeconds();
            s = (s < 10) ? ("0" + s) : s ;

            datetext = datetext + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            strDate = datetext;

            $('#startDate').val(datetext);
        }

    });
} );
```