# Could not fire event when default date selected using Jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need to fire event while default date is selected at the time of page load using Jquery datepicker. I am explaining my code below.

```
<input name="date" type="text" id="alltour" class="datepickerdate" placeholder="" value="" >

$('#alltour').datepicker({
       dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
       minDate: 0,
       beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays,
       onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $('#alltour').val(dateText);
            console.log('selected date',$('#alltour').val());
       }
}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Here when page is loading the default date is selected and when this default date will populate in the field a event should be fired. As per my code its now working for first time default date selected.

Answer (score 0):

There is bug that has been raised to jquery on this context https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8066

However there is a workaround suggested in the question https://stackoverflow.com/a/13693779/5866606 for this by just clicking the current day manually with jquery.

```
$('.ui-datepicker-current-day').click();
```

Here is the fiddle containing the changed code. You can open the console to see the change

https://jsfiddle.net/520vqz7g/

Answer (score 0):

Try `trigger('change')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#alltour').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: 0,
  }).on('change', function(dateText, inst) {
    console.log('selected date', $('#alltour').val());
  }).datepicker("setDate", new Date()).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input name="date" type="text" id="alltour" class="datepickerdate" placeholder="" value="">
```